# Deploy EventGrid using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventgrid

I have an EventGrid for analyzing the device active and inactive status which means Azure IOT collect the information from sensors and publish the event to EventGrid and subscribe to Azure Queue. It is working fine. Now, I want to deploy this EventGrid functionality to cloud using PowerShell. I have checked a lot of EventGrid document deployment using Azure PowerShell. We can deploy the EventGrid with Queue subscription. But could not find any input from IoT. How will we set input from IoT hub?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way to subscribe to and filter all of the events of a resource group. Provided that your IoT hub is part of a resource group, perhaps you can receive all events from it?

I imagine you've tried that though.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-1.8.0

If the above link doesn't help you. I would request you to let me know, –